# How do I enable show_sql or the equivalent in kundera for cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, kundera

I have a requirement to monitor and evaluate based on cql logs.

I have tried to set show.sql/show_sql and show.cql/show_cql in persistence.xml but nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this property in your persistence.xml

```
<property name="kundera.show.query" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that Kundera exposes this. You can try **[Achilles](https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki)**, it does expose all CQL statements, even prepared statements, with bound values:

```
Simple query : [SELECT id,count,name,value FROM clustered WHERE id=8013513484507194368 ORDER BY count ASC LIMIT 3;] with CONSISTENCY LEVEL [ONE] 
Prepared statement : [INSERT INTO clustered(id,count,name,value) VALUES (?,?,?,?);] with CONSISTENCY LEVEL [ONE] 
     bound values: [4369116603855882908, 583011159, name, clustered_value] 
Prepared statement : [UPDATE clustered SET value=? WHERE id=? AND count=? AND name=?;] with CONSISTENCY LEVEL [ONE] 
     bound values: [new_clustered_value, 4945333445409206272, 1627329099, name]
```

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Achilles

Comment: Doesn't answer the question but still a good alternative to look at.